# How to create a sequential RxJava chain from Completable to Single?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have a scenario where I need to create a sequential chain using RxJava in Kotlin. Specifically, I want to create a chain that starts with a Completable and then proceeds to a Single operation.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
class TestRepository {
    fun performCompletableTask(): Completable {
        Timber.v("Migration performCompletableTask")
        return Completable.fromAction {
            // Perform some operation here
            for (i in 1..100) {
                // Do something with the number i
                // Example: Print the number i
                Timber.v("$i ")
            }
        }
    }

    fun performSingleStringTask(): Single<String> {
        Timber.v("Migration performSingleStringTask")
        return Single.fromCallable {
            // Perform some operation here
            val stringBuilder = StringBuilder()
            for (i in 1..100) {
                // Append the number i to the string builder
                stringBuilder.append(i).append(" ")
            }
            // Return the final string
            stringBuilder.toString()
        }
    }

    fun performSingleIntTask(): Single<Int> {
        Timber.v("Migration performSingleIntTask")
        return Single.fromCallable {
            // Perform some operation here
            var sum = 0
            for (i in 1..100) {
                // Accumulate the sum of numbers
                sum += i
            }
            // Return the final sum
            sum
        }
    }
}


 fun testMigration() {
        Timber.v("Performing migration...")

        val completable = testRepository.performCompletableTask()
            .andThen(testRepository.performSingleStringTask())
            .flatMap {
                Timber.v("flatMap Single<String> result: $it")
                testRepository.performSingleIntTask()
            }

        val subscribe = completable
            .subscribe({
                Timber.v("subscribe Single<Int> result: $it")
                Timber.v("Migration completed.")
            }, { error ->
                Timber.e(error, "Error occurred during migration: ${error.message}")
            })
    }
```

In the given code, both performCompletableTask() and performSingleStringTask() are called simultaneously. However, I want to modify the chain to ensure that performSingleStringTask() is called only after performCompletableTask() has completed execution.

Can you suggest how I can modify the code to achieve sequential execution in the RxJava chain? I appreciate any guidance or example code you can provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`performSingleStringTask()` already is only executed after `performCompletableTask()` completes; that is how `andThen` works. It just looks like they run simultaneously because you put the logging outside of the `fromAction` and `fromCallable` operators. Unlike most other RxJava operators, `andThen` does not take a callback, it takes an Rx type directly, so the `performSingleStringTask()` method is called immediately after `performSingleStringTask()` is called, and both are called before `suscribe` is called. However, the callbacks you passed to the `fromAction` and `fromCallable` operators still happen sequentially, starting from the point `subscribe` is called. So the order of operations is:

1. `performCompletableTask()` is called, logs a message, and returns a `Completable`
2. `performSingleStringTask()` is called logs a message, and returns a `Single`, which is passed as a parameter to `andThen()`.
3. `flatMap` is called and is passed a lambda function
4. `subscribe` is called, which triggers the `Completable.fromAction()` callback to run and emit `onComplete` when its finished.
5. The `Single.fromCallable` callback runs and emits `onSuccess` when its finished.